# AWS Javascript SDK : Greengrass createFunctionDefinition

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-iot-greengrass

I'm formatting my parameters according to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Greengrass.html#createFunctionDefinition-property

But for whatever reason its giving me a key error when for "Execution" as well as DefaultConfig

```
Response:

Request ID:
"3ed83472-39af-493b-9df7-7f82d2f14636"

Function Logs:
r: Unexpected key \'Execution\' found in params.InitialVersion.Functions[0].FunctionConfiguration.Environment',
  code: 'MultipleValidationErrors',
  errors: 
   [ { UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'DefaultConfig' found in params.InitialVersion
    at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-
```

and the code

```
GG.createFunctionDefinition({
                                InitialVersion: {  
                                    DefaultConfig: {
                                        Execution: {
                                            IsolationMode: "NoContainer"}
                                            },
                                    Functions: [
                                        {
                                            FunctionArn: "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:644226108543:function:SahmCumminsTelemetryTest:1",
                                            FunctionConfiguration: {
                                                MemorySize: 524288,
                                                Pinned: true,
                                                Timeout: 600,
                                                Environment: {
                                                 AccessSysfs: false,
                                                    Execution: {
                                                        IsolationMode: "NoContainer",
                                                        RunAs: {
                                                            Gid: 0,
                                                            Uid: 0
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            Id: "function_definition",
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                Name: "function_definition",
                            }, function (err, data) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                                }
                                else {
                                    funcArn = data.LatestVersionArn;

                                    };
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: no....JK here you go (i guess its too long here so I'm going to edit the original)

Comment: I think the validator might be expecting `AmznClientToken` to be the first parameter, as it is in the docs.

Comment: I don't think that is it because the code works before I add that part of it in the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is that the configuration data specifies two mutually exclusive options. There is a memory size value specified AND it says it should use "NoContainer". When the Greengrass container isn't in use memory size isn't a valid option.

Try removing memory size and see if that fixes it.

The provisioning code I've shared on Github "scrubs" functions when NoContainer is set to get around this issue. The scrubbing process is to set the memory size to NULL so when it is serialized to JSON the field is missing.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-greengrass-provisioner/blob/e2608654b65682ca9b5b03da962cc8cb29ea1cbf/src/main/java/com/awslabs/aws/greengrass/provisioner/implementations/helpers/BasicGreengrassHelper.java#L390

Comment: That was it, that plus accesssysfs needed to be removed. Thanks!